# update value into another table using trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Create table data with column StudentId (varchar type), Marks (Double). Create table data1 with column StudentId (varchar type), OldMarks (Double),NewMarks,Date.

Create trigger on data table.If mark is changed,create entry in data1 table for student with old marks,new marks & current date.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER marksss ON [dbo].[data] after UPDATE 
AS declare @studentid int; 
declare @marks int; 
declare @xyz int; 
declare @newmarks int; 
declare @oldmarks int; 
select @studentid=i.student_id from inserted i; 
--to fetch inserted values 
select @marks=i.marks from inserted i; 
begin if update(marks) --set @oldmarks=@mark set @newmarks=@marks 
insert into data1(student_id,new_marks,old_marks,date) 
values (@studentid,@newmarks,@oldmarks,getdate()enter code here); 
end 
go
```

the problem is that it does not display old marks

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER marksss
       ON [dbo].[data] after UPDATE
AS
declare @studentid int;
declare @marks int;
declare @xyz int;
declare @newmarks int;
declare @oldmarks int;

select @studentid=i.student_id from inserted i; --to fetch inserted values
select @marks=i.marks from inserted i;

 
 
begin
   if update(marks)
   --set  @oldmarks=@mark
  set  @newmarks=@marks 
  
   
  insert into data1(student_id,new_marks,old_marks,date)
values (@studentid,@newmarks,@oldmarks,getdate()`enter code here`);
end
go

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Comment: For the old value, you need the `deleted` table

Comment: What is the purpose for data1? You could just include a timestamp column in the first table and this would be your historical record. Simply select with  person id and order by timestamp for latest ones.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get what you want. First of all, you want to use an instead of trigger instead. Oracle has a before trigger which is what you ideally need however MSSQL doesn't have this feature so we have to do the passed in update manually too...

Here is the code with the table setup that I used, just changed to suit your needs.

```
CREATE TABLE A (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, SCORE INT)

CREATE TABLE B (ID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES A(ID), SCORE INT, OLDSCORE INT, [date] DATETIME)

GO

CREATE TRIGGER marksss ON A INSTEAD OF UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN 
    IF (SELECT A.SCORE FROM A INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON I.ID = A.ID) != (SELECT I.SCORE FROM INSERTED I)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO B(ID,SCORE,OLDSCORE,[date])
    SELECT I.ID, I.SCORE, A.SCORE, GETDATE()
    FROM INSERTED I
    INNER JOIN A ON I.ID = A.ID 
END
BEGIN
    UPDATE A
    SET SCORE = (SELECT I.SCORE FROM INSERTED I)
END
END
```